# scanf format strings

Tags: c, regex, scanf

I'm trying to learn scanf format strings, and I'm having trouble getting this to work. I'm attempting to read in a string of the format:

"someKey"="someValue"

This is the code I am using:

```
void test()
{
    char buffer[2][128];
    int amountRead;
    char* input = "\"test\"=\"hello\"";
    int result = sscanf(input, "\"%128[a-zA-Z0-9]s\"=\"%128[a-zA-Z0-9]s\"%n", buffer[0], buffer[1], &amountRead);
    printf("input = %s\nresult = %d\nstr1 = %s\nstr2 = %s\namountread = %d\n", input, result, buffer[0], buffer[1], amountRead);
}
```

For some reason, it only manages to scan the first value:

```
input = "test"="hello"
result = 1
str1 = test
str2 = 
amountread = 0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Played with your code a bit, then went to manpage.

> s      Matches a sequence of non-white-space characters;

...

> [      Matches a nonempty sequence of characters from the specified set of accepted characters;

Apparently when using `[` you don't need `s`, so the following does work as expected:

```
int result = sscanf(input, "\"%128[a-zA-Z0-9]\"=\"%128[a-zA-Z0-9]\"%n", buffer[0], buffer[1], &amountRead);
```

Comment: Really weird that it still put "test" into the first string argument.

Comment: It matches "test" then fails to match 's' and stops scanning.

Comment: @charliehorse55 Adding to this answer: you can use `[^\"]` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Comment: That's not the intended effect - I don't want to have spaces or other special characters in the key or value.